# How to set specific property value in model object Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am very new to angular, here what I want to do is I want to set the value of a specific property in the model instead of updating the whole model.

**order-model.ts**

```
export class Order{

constructor(
    public ID: number,
    public Address: string,
    public SupplierName: string
) { }
```

**order.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { Order} from '../order-model'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: 'order.html',
  styleUrls: ['order.css'],
})
export class CreateProductComponent {

order: Order[] = [
    //Now I want to access the property 'Address' to set the value instead of doing like this.
    new Order(0, "QLD", null)
];

constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: order is an array (`Order[]`) but you're trying to assign a single `Order`.  Your `Order` properties are private also with no way to access them.

Comment: @JasonWhite My bad, I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

1)  you can create a getter (and setter as well):

```
constructor(
  public _ID: number,
  public _address: string,
  public _supplierName: string
)

get address(): string {
  return this._address;
}

set address(newName: string) {
  this._address = address;
}
```

2) Better to specify lowercase names for properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class structure you can use where the variables are declared at the top of the class.  Default is public so we don't need to add public to the declarations.  The constructor creates a new object with the inputs, then you can access any field using order.id, order.address, order.supplier.

One final suggestion is the angular style guide [here](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) recommends using camel case for variables.  Example supplierName instead of SupplierName.

```
export class Order {

  id: number;
  address: string;
  supplierName;

  constructor(id: number, address: string, supplierName: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.address = address;
    this.supplierName = supplierName;
  } 
}

const order = new Order(1001, '100 Main St', 'Costco');
console.log('address is:', order.address);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to define your model and accomplish your task. Here is my take using getter/setters retaining the private member variables you used initially in the question.

Order model

```js
export class Order {
  constructor(
    private _id: number,
    private _address: string,
    private _supplierName: string
  ) { }

  get ID() { return this.ID };
  set ID(id: number) { this._id = id };

  get Adress() { return this._address };
  set Address(address: string) { this._address = address };

  get SupplierName() { return this._supplierName };
  set SupplierName(supplierName: string) { this._supplierName = supplierName };
}
```

Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Order } from './order-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  order: Order[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.order.push(new Order(4, 'Downing Street', 'Robert Downing'));

    console.log(this.order);
    /* log:
      _address: "Downing Street"
      _id: 4
      _supplierName: "Robert Downing"
    */

    this.order[0].Address = 'Baker Street';    

    console.log(this.order);
    /* log:
      _address: "Baker Street"
      _id: 4
      _supplierName: "Robert Downing"
    */
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-puvskz)

Answer (score 0):

As long as your constructor args are `public` you should be able to access them without adding getters and setters.  You will only need provide `get`, `set` method if you declare the constructor args `private`.

```js
class Order{
  constructor(
    public ID: number,
    public Address: string,
    public SupplierName: string
  ) { }
}

const order: Order = new Order(1, 'xjdisl1', 'Company Name');
console.log(order.Address);
```